# MobileFirst Studio 8.0 installation

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I have install MobileFirst 8.0.0 studio plugin from eclipse marketplace. But I can not find option to create new MobileFirst project like which I used to find in version 7.1.0.

So there is no support in eclipse for 8.0 version? Only CLI is available for version 8.0? or is there any other way? Can some one help me in this.

Answer (score 2):

In MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 you create either native apps (using Xcode, Android Studio, Visual Studio) and add the SDK to the project, or standard Cordova apps (using the Cordova CLI) and add the MobileFirst Cordova plug-in.

MobileFirst Studio 8.0 for Eclipse is meant to work in conjunction with the THyM plug-in for Eclipse as a way to create an IDE to develop your Cordova application.

Learn more about to get started with development in Eclipse, in this tutorial: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/using-mobilefirst-cli-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

You can still use MFP CLI to deploy the app/artifacts on to MFP server.

For more/clear details please refer the [Migration Cook Book](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/upgrading/migration-cookbook/)